# What are lures for?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I notice a category of items in the inventory called "Lures". What are they for? I guess they're for attracting monsters. If so, what lures would attract what type of creatures?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of the lures list the monsters they attract in their description.

Reprinted below for your convenience:

**Rotten Meat** -- Lure for Nekkers and Trolls

**Bauble** -- Lure for Wraiths and Drowners

**Endrega Gland Extract** -- Lure for Endrega and Arachi

**Phosphorescent Crystal** -- Harpy Lure

**Thumper** -- Bullvore and Rotfiend Lure

(I may be missing some)

Comment: and how do use use them?

Comment: @Bora - not quite sure, honestly. Did stumble upon some other unexpected behavior, however (and this is why I'm not sure; it lost me the only lure I had on me). If a Lure is in the R item slot when you need to use grapeshot to destroy something (for instance, a Nekker Nest), Geralt will place the lure on the object in addition to the bomb.

Comment: the lure attracts the monster, so you could use it to set a bunch of traps around the lure.

Comment: So the monster must already be present? Can't just plant a bauble in the middle of the jungle and have drowners appear?  But if you plant a lure next to a trap while being attacked, it will draw the monster away into the trap?  Is that the idea?

Answer (score 2):

What I do is, setting traps and setting the lure in the middle of the trap (stand on the trap and set lure), or right behind it, so that the monsters walk into the trap while getting to the lure.

They don't work very consistently, though. I've seen monsters walk right past me and into the lure, or just ignore the lure and attack me instead.

For the details on which monster is lured to which, see Raven's post.